# Is there a way to tell CMFCColorButton, what colors not to present

Tags: button, mfc

Is there a way to tell `CMFCColorButton` what set of colors to display?

For example, when press, show me just orange white and black.

## Update

I've tried by defining:

```
PALETTEENTRY  palleteEntries[2] = 
{
    /*index 0 black*/
    {0,0,0,PC_EXPLICIT},
    /*index 1 white*/
    {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,PC_EXPLICIT},
};

CPalette colorPalette;
colorPalette.SetPaletteEntries(0,2,palleteEntries);
```

Then I get an assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CPalette colorPalette;
> colorPalette.SetPaletteEntries(0,2,palleteEntries);
> ```

At this point `colorPalette` is just a C++ object, not `HPALETTE` resource object. `SetPaletteEntries` makes WinAPI call for a non-existing `HPALETTE` and fails. This is one of those times when MFC is not being helpful by hiding everything. But the debugger helps to point out the problem.

Start with `LOGPALETTE` instead. `LOGPALETTE::palVersion` should be `0x0300` otherwise `CreatePalette` fails. Use this instead:

```
CPalette pal;
LOGPALETTE* lg = (LOGPALETTE*)malloc(sizeof(LOGPALETTE) + 5 * sizeof(PALETTEENTRY));
lg->palNumEntries = 5;
lg->palVersion = 0x0300;
lg->palPalEntry[0] = { 255,0,0,0 };
lg->palPalEntry[1] = { 0,255,0,0 };
lg->palPalEntry[2] = { 0,0,255,0 };
lg->palPalEntry[3] = { 0,0,0,0 };
lg->palPalEntry[4] = { 255,255,255,0 };
if(pal.CreatePalette(lg))
{
    m_myColorBtn.SetPalette(&pal);
}
free(lg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `CPalette` object.

Use void `CMFCColorButton::SetPalette(CPalette* pPalette)` to force usage of this palette.